# React Native Navigation - Moving between routes on same screen with different params

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I have React Native app that shows people profiles (like Facebook for example). I use React Navigation to navigate between screens.

On person page, you can press on another person item and it navigates to the same person page with different person id.

This how I navigate when person item is pressed:

```
props.navigation.push('PersonPage', {personId: person.id})
```

It is working and navigates to new screen, and also fetching the data correctly (person details), but before the page renders with the new data, I get this error:
`JSON value '<null>' of type NSNull cannot be converted to NSNumber`.
When I click on dismiss the error, I can see the full profile and everything is good.
but when I go back (`props.navigation.goBack()`), it moves back to the previous page (person page) but the last person's id is lost and the page is empty.

How can I handle it properly? why do I get this error? and how can I save the previous person's id when going back?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please provide the code section that cause error.

Comment: I don't know what causes the error. The error isn't clear and not specific. All I know is that it happens after I navigate to the same screen with different params. Anyway, I care more about finding the right way to navigate between these screens. Thank you!

Comment: which state management tool you are using?

Comment: I'm using Redux

Comment: yes, so you should prevent the screen from updating new data when the page is in background.do some logic in shouldComponentUpdate method

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not provided your code, I have added the steps that I have used to handle navigation to screen with parameters. Could you please try this and let me know If you find any difficulties

```
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      personId: 0,
      data: [],
    };
    } 



    componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ personId: this.props.navigation.state.params.personId })
    this._getPageData()

    }



    static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    // For differnt personid, ie if props changes
    if (nextProps.navigation.state.params.personId !== prevState.personId) {
      return {
        personId: nextProps.navigation.state.params.personId
      }
    }
    return null;
    }




    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.props.navigation.state.params.personId !== prevProps.navigation.state.params.personId) {
      this._getPageData();// Fetch data again if props changes
    }
    }



    _getPageData(){

    // Console.log(this.state.personId) and see if correct value is showing
    // fetch data based on  this.state.personId

    }
```

Add you navigation press as follows

```
    onPress{() => {

        const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
        routeName: 'YourRoute',
        params: { personId: YOURPERSONID },
        });
        this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);

    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using navigation.navigate in place of navigation.push ? because what push does is it explicitly pushes that page in a new stack , and hence it doesnt retrieve the old persons id while pressing navigation.goBack(). So either you explicitly call this.props.navigation.push('Person',{id:id}) when you are pressing the backButton of the screen, that is while going back.

You can try with navigation.navigate and see if that help.s

Feel free for doubts. Ill help :D

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried - ```props.navigation.navigate({
                routeName: 'PersonPage',
                params: {personId: person.id},
                key: 'PersonPage' + (Math.random () * 10000)
            });```. It acts the same for me..

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your component class

```
 state = {
    viewVisibility: true,
  };
  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    if (this.state.viewVisibility) return true;
    return false;
  }
```

when navigating new user page
call setState also

```
this.setState({
visibility:false})
```